# Unwanted characters inserted into PDO prepared statement when using associative array key

Tags: sql, insert, pdo

I created a PDO statement which uses an associative array key however when the SQL is executed " \ " and " ' "are added in, how do I prevent this?

Here is the query

```
public function queryUpdateClasses($classesToUpdate,$packageId){
        $sql = "SELECT class.ClassId FROM class JOIN package ON package.PackageId = class.PackageId WHERE class.ClassName = ? AND package.PackageId = ?";
        $query = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
        foreach($classesToUpdate as $updateKey=>$updateValue){
            echo $updateKey;
            $query->execute(array($updateKey,$packageId));
        }
    }
```

Here is the output to the log file

```
98 Query    SELECT class.ClassId FROM class JOIN package ON package.PackageId = class.PackageId WHERE class.ClassName = '\'LogActivityTable\'' AND package.PackageId = '69'
```

When you the `$updateKey;` is echoed out it just shows 'LogActivityTable'.

Comment: Are you pre-escaping outside of this function before sending it in? Most likely you are adding those `'` somewhere and it is a case of removing that code.

Comment: Looks like $updateKey contains `'LogActivityTable'` with quotes and not just `LogActivityTable`

Comment: `'LogActivityTable'` is retrieved by querying the database and already contains the quotation marks.

Comment: Your gonna need to explain more than that...like how?

Comment: Can you post it and mark it as the answer when it allows you to so others who find this page will know what to do? thanks in advance :)